# I can' t find general solution of the following equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Will we solve the equation as PDE or ODE? What are the methods of solution?

$$x\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}+yw=\frac 1 {1+x^{2y}}$$

**My solution:**

it is a linear ODE which is

$$w'+\frac y x w=\frac 1 {x(1+x^{2y})}.$$ If we use integration factor, we get $\mathrm{d}(x^y \, w)=\dfrac{x^{y-1}}{1+x^{2y}} \, \mathrm{d}x$

But I can' t do the rest of solution. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try with Maple or any math software ?

Comment: I corrected some typos and the integration factor, which should be $x^y$. Are you having trouble with the integral in the LHS?

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $x$?

Comment: trouble with RHS

Comment: No @mathreadler

Comment: Then i suppose Morenos hint could help.

Comment: The solution is $w=\frac{x^{-y}}{2}ln(1+x^{2y})+x^{-y}f(y)$, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$ \int \frac{x^{y-1}}{1+x^{2y}} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{y}\int \frac{y \, x^{y-1}}{1+(x^y)^2} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{y}\arctan{(x^y)} $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The solution is $w=\frac{x^{-y}}{2}ln(1+x^{2y})+x^{-y}f(y)$, right ?

Comment: Not quite, let me edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please, @captain23, complete your question with your steps so we can see where you made a mistake easier.